# Error while trying to read a message from a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have an MBean that is trying to get a message present on a queue:

```
public String republishMessage(String dlQueueName, String exchangeName) {
    try {
        ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/rabbit.xml");
        AmqpTemplate template = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
        Message testMessage = template.receive(dlQueueName);
        return "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return "Failure";
    }
```

When it creates the context from the given xml file , it is not replacing the property values.
For example:

```
<property name="host" value="${rabbit.connection.host}" />
```

It is setting the host value to ${rabbit.connection.host} and not replacing it with the value from the property file.

What changes need to be made so that it reads the values from the property file?

Comment: Do you have a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your spring config?

Comment: Yes, would be great, if you share your `rabbit.xml` config

Comment: In any case, creating a new application context on each execution just for this function seems a bit too much overhead. Why not just create the template in Java? At the very least, you should `destroy()` the context before returning.

Comment: It worked after I added the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.
@GaryRussell - You are right about the overhead. I will create the template in Java